# Omit certain results in a subdocument MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am querying a list of items and only returning the items with contain a given ID in the `provider_cost_dict`. For instance, if I pass `providerId = 10001`, then only items with an entry in `provider_cost_dict` that match the provider ID will return.

How can I modify my code so that I can omit all the provider_cost_dict's that do not match the provider ID?

Here is my current code:

```
var procedures = db.collection('procedures');

var query = {};
query['provider_cost_dict.' + req.query.providerId] = {$exists: true };

procedures.find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    // Send the result back via JSON.
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(result, null, 3));

});
```

Here is what my response looks like:

```
{
          "_id": "57c62cb53673aaf5f6beacf9",
          "natl_total_cost": 1274787840,
          "natl_average": 8338.487,
          "natl_report_count": 152880,
          "name": "COPD (WITH MAJOR COMPLICATIONS)",
          "provider_cost_dict": {
             "10001": {
                "report_count": 144,
                "total_cost": 957334,
                "average_cost": 6648.153
             },
             "10005": {
                "report_count": 200,
                "total_cost": 1321644,
                "average_cost": 6608.22
             },
             "10006": {
                "report_count": 214,
                "total_cost": 1345658,
                "average_cost": 6288.1216
```

If I passed `10001 how could I make my return look like:

```
{
          "_id": "57c62cb53673aaf5f6beacf9",
          "natl_total_cost": 1274787840,
          "natl_average": 8338.487,
          "natl_report_count": 152880,
          "name": "COPD (WITH MAJOR COMPLICATIONS)",
          "provider_cost_dict": {
             "10001": {
                "report_count": 144,
                "total_cost": 957334,
                "average_cost": 6648.153
             }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#find-projection) to the query so that only your desired cost dict is shown like so

```
var query = { 'provider_cost_dict.10001': { $exists: true } };
var project = { 
    'natl_total_cost': 1,
    'natl_average': 1,
    'natl_report_count': 1,
    'name': 1,        
    'provider_cost_dict.10001': 1 
};
procedures.find(query, project).toArray( ...
```